# Getting a specific date in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have searched a lot of sites. This code is given. But by writing this all the entries containing "2021" are displayed when I need only the entries having date as "10-10-2021". pls guide what to do

**{ "query": { "term": { "date": { "value": "10-10-2020" } } } }**

Comment: What is the mapping of the date field?

Answer (score 0):

Is your field indexed as a date or a keyword? Index it as a date and instead of a terms query you should use a range query to get documents within a specific span of time: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html